# Help with undestanding convolution. Which interval I need to choose?

Tags: probability, statistics

at this time I'm having problems in solving exercise of convolution, more precisley obtainig the correct intervals for my exercise.
 My question is where I can find more resourses where explain why they choose such limit of integration.
 For example, in the following exercise

1) Let X and Y be independent uniformly distributed variables, U(0,10) and U(0,20), respectively. The pdf of Z=X+Y is, which is solve in this webpage : https://probabilityexam.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/examples-of-convolution-continuous-case/
   I can not undestand the general procedure in wich the diferent intervals are choosen.

I'm sorry if is a silly question but I was all day try to solve an exercise but I never could have the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site provides a few diagrams. I recommend that you read it one more time.

Notice that we are interested in the line $x+y =z$. Recall that $0\leq x\leq 10$ and $0\leq y \leq 20$. In the lower region, notice that the density lies in the blue region. If integrating over $dx$, then  $0\leq x\leq z$.

[image]

In the next region, the line of interest is still $x+y=z$, but now 
$0\leq x\leq 10$; each red line is of constant length.
[image]

I'll let you figure out figure 4 on the site for yourself now.